# Replicating DOORS structure in windows

Tags: ibm-doors

I'm trying to create a script that will replicate a DOORS structure in a windows file structure. The idea is to run the script and have the folder structure from the current location downwards replicated in a windows folder structure of the users' choosing. I'm brand new to DXL but I've found the mkdir() function. When using it I seem to have problems when giving it a full filepath i.e. C:\output\folder1\ . In this case it would not create the structure properly unless C:\output already exists.

My question is, is there a way to make it so that multiple folder levels can be created at once, or is there a better way to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steve's answer was correct, although in my case it made more sense to use recursion, due to some other stuff I also had to do.

This code was modified from a version I found on the IBM Developer Works forum, but I cannot find the source, I'll link it if I find it again

```
void  RecurseFolder(Folder fld)
{   // Deal RECURSIVELY with sub-folders, and then all modules in this folder

    if (!fileExists_(g_base_dir "\\" name(fld)) && !(name(current) == name(fld)))
    {
        mkdir(g_base_dir "\\")
    }

    Skip skpItems = createString()
    Item itm
    string NameItem
    Folder fldNew

    // Stage in Skip, key is name which is Alpha order
    for itm in fld do
    {  
        put (skpItems, fullName(itm), itm)
    }

    // Recurse through sub-folders
    for itm in skpItems do
    {  
        string base_dir = g_base_dir
        NameItem = (string key skpItems)
        if (type(itm) == "Folder" or type(itm) == "Project")
        {  
            fldNew = folder(NameItem)
            g_base_dir = g_base_dir "\\" name(fldNew)
            RecurseFolder(fldNew)   // *** RECURSION ***
            g_base_dir = base_dir
        }
        else if    (type(itm) == "Formal")
        {

            //open module for reading - silent mode, standard view
            Module m = read(fullName(itm), false, true)
            if (NameItem != "")
            {
                if (!null export(base_dir "\\" name(itm) ".xml"))
                {
                    errorBox "Export failed! - \n" base_dir "\\" name(itm) ".xml"
                }
            }

            //if module is not visible
            if (!isVisible(m))
            {
                // close it to improve performance
                close m
            }
        }
       else {} //Nothing to do
    }
    delete(skpItems)
} // end RecurseFolder()
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to create your base level folder first (either in the script or externally), then as you loop through each Project/Folder in DOORS, create a folder for that Item. For example:

```
mkdir("C:/output")
string p_name = ""
Item i
Project p
for p_name in database do {
  mkdir("C:/output/" p_name)
  p = project(p_name)
  for i in p do {
    if((type(i) "" == "Folder") || (type(i) "" == "Project")) {
      mkdir("C:/output/" fullName(i))
    }
  }
}
```

This should get you started, I didn't have time to test it but you can modify it to your needs.